# Contents of a table, present in a Beamer Frame, are lost, when beamerarticle is used to convert it to a document

Tags: tables, beamerarticle

I have a beamer slide with a table defined in `slides.tex` as below:

```
\begin{frame}{Results: Partitions-Medial Computation}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}[h]{@{}r r r r @{}}
\toprule
{\bf Type } & {\bf Shape } & {\bf Partitions} & {\bf Midcurves}\\
\midrule
%
%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

I need to prepare a document using these slides so I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
%
\input{slides} % as shown above
%
\end{document}
```

Contents of the table are not shown.

When I comment-out `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` and retain the `tabular` env., it works fine. But with this I am losing `caption/label` that comes with the `table`.

Any idea?

Comment: Don't use `\bf`. It is obsolete. LaTeX 2e uses `\bfseries` instead which adjusts things correctly. I get the same result whether I comment out the `table` environment or not. However, does the `[h]` in the `tabular` setting actually do anything? Tabulars are not floats so they are always placed 'here'. Does the `[h]` mean something else in this context? Your MWE does not demonstrate the problem. For one thing, there is no caption. For another, it works fine. You can, however, always use the `capt-of` package to allow captions without floats.